# Swift callkit sometimes can't activate loudspeaker after received call (only incoming call)

Tags: swift, callkit, speaker

after follow @Marco comment, i updated code like below, but still not working, the loudspeaker sometimes can not enabled

Before report new call/ user accepted call I called the 2 methods below:

```
configureAudioSessionToDefaultSpeaker()
```

```
func configureAudioSessionToDefaultSpeaker() {
    let session = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
        do {
            try session.setCategory(AVAudioSession.Category.playAndRecord, mode: .default)
            try session.setActive(true)
            try session.setMode(AVAudioSession.Mode.voiceChat)
            try session.setPreferredSampleRate(44100.0)
            try session.setPreferredIOBufferDuration(0.005)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to configure `AVAudioSession`: \(error)")
        }
}
```

I updated more code:

```
func startCallWithPhoneNumber(call : CallInfoModel) {
        
        configureAudioSessionToDefaultSpeaker()
        currentCall = call
        if let unwrappedCurrentCall = currentCall {
            let handle = CXHandle.init(type: .generic, value: unwrappedCurrentCall.CallerDisplay ?? UNKNOWN)
            let startCallAction = CXStartCallAction.init(call: unwrappedCurrentCall.uuid, handle: handle)
            let transaction = CXTransaction.init()
            transaction.addAction(startCallAction)
            requestTransaction(transaction: transaction)
            
            self.provider?.reportOutgoingCall(with: startCallAction.callUUID, startedConnectingAt: nil)
            
        }
    }
```

```
 func provider(_ provider: CXProvider, perform action: CXAnswerCallAction) {
        
            
        configureAudioSessionToDefaultSpeaker()

        delegate?.callDidAnswer()
        action.fulfill()
        currentCall?.isAccepted = true
        let sb = UIStoryboard(name: "main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = sb.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SingleCallVC") as! SingleCallVC
        vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
        vc.callObj = currentCall
        vc.isIncoming = true
        let appDelegate = AppDelegate.shared
        appDelegate.window?.rootViewController?.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
    }
```

My call almost work normally but sometime loudspeaker can not be enabled. I read many documents but nothing worked for me. Could someone give me some advice? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You're configuring the AudioSession two times. The `RTCAudioSession` it's a proxy of `AVAudioSession`. You should do only one configuration to avoid unexpected results. `RTCAudioSession` should expose all the methods of the `AVAudioSession`, so you should be able to make all the configurations you want inside `configureRtcAudioSession()` and eliminate `configureAudioSessionToDefaultSpeaker()` or viceversa. I'm not sure if it will solve your issue but at least it should help to avoid unexpected behaviors.

Comment: Hi, first time im only set configureAudioSession only one time in diDAcceptCall method, but i make 40% of my call have no sound , but when try to above code it"s only remain 5%.

Answer (score 1):

I've had success with enabling the speaker using the method below.

```
let audioQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "audio")    

func setSpeaker(_ isEnabled: Bool) {
    audioQueue.async {
        defer {
            AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().unlockForConfiguration()
        }
        
        AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().lockForConfiguration()
        do {
            try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().overrideOutputAudioPort(isEnabled ? .speaker : .none)
        } catch {
            debugPrint(error.localizedDescription)
        }
    }
}

// Enables the audio speaker.
setSpeaker(true)

// Disables the audio speaker.
setSpeaker(false)
```

Comment: What is `lockForConfiguration` and `unlockForConfiguration `

Comment: These are used to grant your application exclusive access to the device's hardware when making changes. https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1387810-lockforconfiguration